# Deploy React SPA

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am completely new to react but have been developing a React SPA using the `create-react-app` package. I have also been developing an API using Laravel and Laravel Sanctum. My API's endpoints are all at `api.example.com`. I would like to have my SPA at `example.com`. Currently the API and SPA are in different repositories. I have never deployed a React app and I am not sure how to combine these to work properly.

It may not be relevant by my Laravel API was created on and running on a Homestead vagrant box and the SPA is just running on `localhost:3000` currently.

This question may be too broad but any links to relevant information or examples are appreciated.

I need to know how to properly use `npm`/`craco build` to package the SPA and then how to combine this with my Laravel API. I would assume I can keep these in different repos.

My SPA needs to be at `example.com` to be able to communicate with `api.example.com` to use Sanctums CSRF features.

Currently reading [this document](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)

So running `npm run-script build` will run `craco build` and create minified and compiled js and css files in a build directory. I now need to know how to take this build directory and deploy it to `example.com` so as to communicate with `api.example.com`. Would I add this directory somewhere in the API's repository?

Comment: so what is your question or problem?

Answer (score 1):

Single Page Applications are fundementally just web pages.

Therefor, you would need to get the build output, host them in a server, and finally setup the domain so that it points to this server.

**1. Building the application**

When you run `cracao build`, you get a `build` folder with the 'production ready' build. The build does a few optimisations(such as bundeling the app for browseers that don't support modules, minifying for space, etc.) and gives the output in the build folder.

**2. Hosting the application**

Once built, you can host your app on any server(even someething like S3 would work fine) that you have access to with a fixed IP. Now you should be able to visit the IP directly and view the site!

But the application funtionality would probably break becauses (as you mentioned) CORS would prevent access from different domains.

To fix this, you need to setup the nameserver to point the domain to the new IP.

**3. Continuouts Deployment(optional)**

You could probably setup a CI/CD pipeline to automate the application build and upload process as it can get tedious. The process for this would be running cracao buld and uploading the output to the correct directory.

**Can you maintain the two repos?**

Yes! The although they need to share the same domain, you can keep the apps in two repos and have two different CI/CD pipelines to deploy your applications to the correct places.